# Performance comparison of data retrieving between VIEW and TABLE

Tags: sql, view

I have a View that has structure exactly same as the query to generate record in the Table. 
But the time to execute the select statement as below by using View is taking longer time if compare to Table.

1. Is that mean View is taking longer time to retrieve the data if compare to table?
2. If I have huge data, that is more suitable to use Table instead of View?

select count(*) from XYZ_VIEW  -- this is a view which returns record by using **4min4sec** ,count = 5896

select count(*) from XYZ --this is a table which return return record **less than 1 second** ,count = 5896

Comment: Check the source of the view & it should give you an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't show the query behind the view but I assume it involves some joining to expose normalized data and/or other processing. Here's how you work with views in this regard.

Views should not (as in *never*) be the target of an unfiltered query. Actually, this should be discouraged against tables but they are sometimes necessary during testing. Fortunately, these queries are almost never justified or even necessary in production code.

And since you don't really care about performance during testing but rather performance during production, then you haven't said anything that suggests you might have a problem. That's right, four minutes against one second for the query you show is meaningless. Many of my views (if not most) would give similar results.

Instead, use a query that would more likely be used in production. Using timing methods with millisecond precision, use a query more in the form:

```
select ...
from   table/view
where  <typical filtering criteria>;
```

That will give you more useful information. Depending on your particular application and requirements, an acceptable range would be 10-20%. That is, if the table returns the result in 30 ms, the view is good if it returns the same result in less than about 36 ms.

You are using a view probably because it manipulates the data in some way to present the data more favorably in some way. This processing is overhead you will not have when you query the tables directly. When you omit filtering, you perform that processing on every row of the underlying table(s), probably needlessly. When you do something particularly stupid like `select count(*)`, you perform all that extra processing for no benefit whatsoever.

When you filter the query, the extra processing is performed only on the qualifying result set. Should that result set be only one row, the processing will be performed only on the single row, rendering the performance from the view (depending, of course, on the exact amount and type of processing) practically indistinguishable from the table.

I always recommend the use of views -- lots and lots of views -- to present your users with data in whatever form is best for their various purposes. Test those views, by all means. But use meaningful tests.